# Suppose that $|x-4|\leq1 $

Tags: calculus

EDIT: Okay I got it now.

Take original:

$-1\leq x-4\leq1$

Times by $(x+4)$ on all sides

$-(x+4)\leq x^2-16 \leq x+4$

The most $x+4$ can be is 9 so,

$|x^2-16| \leq 9$

---

Word for word:

> Suppose that $|x-4|\leq 1$.
>
> (a) What is the maximum possible value for $|x+4|$?
>
> (b) Show that $|x^2-16|\leq 9$

---

My main trouble is with (b).

For (a) I did this:

$|x-4|\leq1$

$-1\leq x-4\leq1$

Add 8 to all sides:

$7\leq x+4\leq9$

So the greatest possible value is 9. How do I solve (b) though?

**EDIT**: I changed the inequality on (b)

Comment: b) is wrong. Indeed, if $|x-4|\leq 1$ then $3\leq x\leq 5$, and so for example, for $x=4$, $|x^2-16|=0<9$

Comment: the book's wrong or my method?

Comment: The inequality in $(b)$ is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that (b) is impossible.

$$|x-4|\le 1 \implies 3\le x\le 5$$

$$\implies 9\le x^2 \le 25$$
$$\implies -7 \le x^2-16 \le 9 $$
$$\implies 7 \le |x^2-16|\le 9 $$

Comment: Did you see my edit? I think I did it right. Oh the absolute bars

Comment: I did not see it when I started to type the answer

Comment: @mike: I edited your post by mistake.

Comment: (+1) that's what I noticed too? By the way I did not see your answer untill I posted mine.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal, no problem!

Comment: Ah I hadn't thought of solving it that way. I'm sure that will save me some time in the future

Answer (score 0):

Hint: (a) Use the rule $$|y|\le a\hspace{2mm}\longrightarrow\hspace{2mm}-a\le y\le a$$ and here for $y=x-4$.

For (b) you should note that $x^2-16=(x-4)(x+4)$ and use (a) to conclude.

Remark: the rule is intuitively true since $|y|\le a$ means the distance of $y$ from the origin is less than or equal to $a$, so the value of $y$ can't exceed the particular interval $[-a,a]$ which you can see by drawing a diagram.

Comment: That's just for (a) though, right? I need (b)

Answer (score 0):

For $(b)$ you have the wrong inequality. It should be $|x^2-19|\leq 16$ since we have been given

$$ |x-4| \leq 1 \implies 3\leq x \leq 5 \implies 9\leq x^2 \leq 25 $$

$$\implies -7  \leq x^2-16 \leq 9 \dots\,. $$

Can you conclude?

Answer (score 0):

For b) consider $x^2-16 = (x+4)(x-4)$

Answer (score 0):

If $|x - 4| \leq 1$, using that $$|a| - |b| \leq |a-b| \leq \delta \implies |x| \leq \delta + |a|$$
we get that $|x - 4| \leq 1 \implies |x| \leq 5$. By triangle inequality, you get:
$$|x + 4| \leq |x| + 4 \leq 5 + 4 = 9$$

For the second part, notice that: $$|x^2 - 16| = |x-4||x+4| \geq~ ????$$

(**Hint:** use item (a))